# How to customize fields_for

Tags: ruby-on-rails, for-loop, field

I'm a rails newbie, today I got a problem with fields_for. Hope anyone can help me.
I have a model project:

```
class Project < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates :project_name, presence: true,uniqueness: true  
  validates :plan_time, presence: true
  has_many :tasks, dependent: :destroy
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :tasks, allow_destroy: true
end
```

**and a model task:**

```
class Task < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :project
  validates :user_id, presence: true
  validates :project_id, presence:true
end
```

but when I made a form_for project:

```
<%= form_for(@project, do |f| %>
  <%= f.fields_for :tasks do |tasks_for_form|%>
  <%= render 'task_fields', f: tasks_for_form%>
<%end%>
```

...
it render all the existing task of the project in db. plz help me!

Comment: Kindly post your Project Controller & task_field partial!

Answer (score 1):

That's what `fields_for` does, what are you expecting it to do?

If you want only fields for a new task, then you need to [pass in a record object](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper.html#method-i-fields_for) to the builder, for example:

```
<%= f.fields_for :tasks, @project.tasks.new do |tasks_for_form| %>
```

If you want add/remove functionality, you need to add that yourself, check out the [cocoon gem](https://github.com/nathanvda/cocoon) which makes it simple to do so.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure you've got end inside partial, but the end is required when fields_for has initiated.

```
<%= form_for(@project, do |f| %>
    <%= f.fields_for :tasks do |tasks_for_form|%>
        <%= render 'task_fields', f: tasks_for_form%>
    <% end %>
<% end %>
```